# Can I add Google Analytics to a Chrome extension which doesn't have a popup.html?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-analytics

My chrome extension is recognising a specific tab's URL, and then, on icon click, it modifies that active tab's content. 
I would like to gauge the usage of it, in some way. This is the extension's logic:

```
- manifest.json [injecting jquery & jquery plugin]
- background.js [ on extension's icon click, it executes content_script.js and tracking.js]
- icon
- content_script.js [ it modifies page content ]
- tracking.js (GA code, as provided by google Analytics then modified according to https://davidsimpson.me/2014/05/27/add-googles-universal-analytics-tracking-chrome-extension/ );
```

---

I would like to see how many times extension's button is clicked. I tried adding the appropriate permissions to manifest.json:

```
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com; object-src 'self'"
```

and adding Analytics code to a separate .js file (tracking.js), and executing it when the extension's icon is clicked, as specified in background.js below:

```
chrome.browserAction.onCLicked.addListener(
function(tab) {
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file:
"content_script.js"});
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file:
"tracking.js"});
});
```

.. it doesn't work, in the sense that Google Analytics is telling me 'tracking not installed', and I cannot think of another way of adding it.

How can I see this extension's usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is to inject tracking into a tab as a content script.

Tracking works by adding another `<script>` tag into the page, which kicks it out of your [content script's isolated context](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment) and into the page's context. That's why your script can't see the tracking enabled (and you possibly just broke the page's own tracking too).

You need to install the tracking code in your background page and send events from there. To do so, simply include `tracking.js` to the list of background scripts; after that, send events in the usual GA way.

Comment: I tried specifying tracking.js in the manifest, along with jquery.min.js - I do not want to track specific events in the page, I just want a very basic usage tracking. I removed the following from tracking.js, and included it in content_script.js, which runs when ext icon is clicked:
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-YY', 'auto');
ga('set', 'checkProtocolTask', function(){}); 
ga('send', 'pageview');
Still doesn't work.

Comment: Again. You _can't_ run tracking in the content script. It must run in a background page. Let me add a link to my answer so you can see the problem better. If you still don't understand, update the question with your manifest so I can answer better.

Comment: I downloaded analytics.js and included it in extension files. Removed 'tracking.js' and now GA still shows 'tracking not installed'.. however it shows me one user (only me atm), and several page views. Could it be that 'Tracking not installed' message is due to GA checking for the non-existent website name I was required to put, when setting up the analytics for this extension? I'm not even sure it works right now.

Comment: I am marking your solution as accepted - thank you - I followed the isolated worlds logic and it seems I get usage reports now. It still comes up as 'tracking Not Installed' under '.JS Tracking Info' Admin section in GA.

Comment: Isn't there a way to use a CDN loaded script in the same context as chrome extension's JS context?

Comment: Well.. You can load it with XHR and use `executeScript`, but that's about it. If the script itself tries to manipulate `<script>` tags, then no.